# problem with react-native-navigation installation instructions assuming some code does not exist in AppDelegate

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation, velo

I am attempting to install react-native-navigation and am following the instructions from https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing at the section for editing ios files. The instructions tell me to edit the AppDelegate.m. The instructions tell me to add this code and the end result should look like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { ... }
```

and the end result should look like this

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
 #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
 #import <React/RCTRootView.h>
 #import <ReactNativeNavigation/ReactNativeNavigation.h>

 @implementation AppDelegate

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
     [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];

     return YES;
 }

 @end
```

but my AppDelegate.m looks nothing like this? instead it looks like this...

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */



#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"planzu"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

how should I proceed? Am I supposed to eliminate the top and bottom methods? or just replace the event call 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just modify your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to be as mentioned in the RNN documentation. This is the entry point for RNN and it replaces the usual react-native setup of creating the bridge and the root-view.

You can leave the other two methods (`openURL` and `sourceURLForBridge`) as is.